# Max number of data in file in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, visual-studio-2012, limit

I'm trying to edit some data in a file with Visual Studio C#. I've tried using both

```
StreamReader and File.ReadAllLines / ReadAllText
```

Both results give me 3414 lines of content. I've jut used Split('\n') after "ReadAllText". But when I check the use the following command on linux I get the follow results:

```
cat phase1_promoter_data_PtoP1.txt | wc
```

Output:

```
 184829 164686174 1101177922
```

So about 185.000 lines and 165 million words. A word count on Visual Studio gives me about 19 million.

So my question is, am I reading the file wrong or does Visual Studio have a limit on how much data it will read at once? My file takes about about 1 GB space.

Here's the code I use:

```
try
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("phase1_promoter_data_PtoP1.txt"))
    {
        String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        String[,] data = new String[184829, 891];
        //List<String> data2 = new List<String>();

        string[] lol = line.Split('\n');

        for (int i = 0; i < lol.Length; i++)
        {
            String[] oneLine = lol[i].Split('\t');
            //List<String> singleLine = new List<String>(lol[i].Split('\t'));


            for (int j = 0; j < oneLine.Length; j++)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(i + " - " + lol.Length + " - " + j + " - " + oneLine.Length);
                data[i,j] = oneLine[j];
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(data[3413,0]);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{                 
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: If that file contains more than 3414 lines, this code will throw an array out of bounds exception as soon as it encounters the 3415th line. I'm also not sure your `String line` can contain 1 GB of text next to your `string[] lol` which will contain the same, but split on newline. Are you sure you're looking at the same file as the one you feed to `cat`?

Comment: My bad, I changed the size of my array, because I believed my output was wrong. But I get no exception, because there are in fact 3414 lines loaded into the array.

Comment: Perhaps some lines have \r and some have \r\n or \n separators, and wc is treating them differently from ReadAllLines()?

Comment: Do you have sample data for the file? `wc` uses different types of whitespace to find "words" - you only only ever split by `\t`.

Comment: String can have upto 2 GB, or about 1 billion characters. So I dont think that file is is a problem

Comment: I'm certain the 2 files are the same. I opened the file that I a giving to Visual Studio and checked. I made a sample here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9j2yid2puj1afcl/myData.txt?dl=0 - It contains about 6000 lines of the original file.

Comment: There are a great number of tab characters (`'\t'`) in that file. Perhaps that's significant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file in your dropbox contains `6043` lines.

Both

```
Debug.Print(File.ReadAllLines(fPath).Count().ToString());
```

And

```
Debug.Print(File.ReadAllText(fPath).Split('\n').Count().ToString());
```

Show the same results (Using VS 2013 .NET 4.5)

I was able to cycle through each line with..

```
 using (var sr = new StreamReader(fPath))
 {
     while (!sr.EndOfStream)
     {
         Debug.Print(sr.ReadLine());
     }
 }
```

And

```
 foreach(string line in File.ReadAllLines(fPath))
 {
     Debug.Print(line);
 }
```

Instead of reading the entire file into a `string` at once, try one of the loops above and build an array as you cycle through.